# How can I set up a website through an ssh tunnel?

Tags: networking, ssh, tunnel

Suppose I have a small http server, running on something like a raspberry pi, and I want to share it with the world, but **don't want to use port forwarding**. Now, I know that this is possible using services like `localtunnel.me`, but I've also been lead to believe that this is possible using only ssh. So, my question is, **how can I use a ssh tunnel to direct my google domains website to my http server?** Is this possible? Or would I need another server to do the port forwarding in the end? I *could* just use `localtunnel` or a similar alternative, but I've read that this is only good for testing, and shouldn't be used in practice.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need another server (either with a public IP address, or with a port forward of its own) to be the other end of the ssh tunnel. It's actually a lot like port forwarding on your router, except that instead of forwarding a port from your router to a computer behind your router, you're forwarding a port from one computer to another that might be far far away (network-wise).

Also, I'd put this in the same testing-only category as localtunnel.me. A port forward would perform much better (even on a pi).